# Angular HttpClient Response not updating html until second click

Tags: angular, ngrx

---

I have been wondering about Angular for a while, and last week i decided to dig in. It has quite amazing features and libraries, yet little bit complex architecture. I am now studying on ngrx library to understand it completely. But before that,

Something confuses me a lot and couldn't figure out why ?

On my component, i have a button that loads items such like tasks assigned to me from Api service. i get the data and log it to console but template does not update it until i click second time to the button. What is that i am missing ?.

Thank you.

```
// Angular
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
// RXJS
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, tap, skip, take, delay ,map} from 'rxjs/operators';import { of, Subscription, Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState } from '../../../../core/reducers';
import {TaskService} from '../../../../core/task'



@Component({
  selector: 'kt-taskmanager-mytasks',
  templateUrl: './mytasks.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,

})
export class taskManagerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


  calendarPlugins = [dayGridPlugin];
  Task = "Hello World"
    message : Observable<any> 
    tasks : Observable<any[]>

    // Subscriptions
    private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];


    constructor(
        private store: Store<AppState>,
    private http: TaskService,

) {}

    ngOnInit() {

  }


    onClickMe() {
        this.message =  this.http.getAllTasks()
        this.message.pipe(      

        tap( r => {this.tasks = r['results'],console.log(this.tasks)},
        err => console.error(err)
        ))

        .subscribe()
    }
    /**
     * On Destroy
     */
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscriptions.forEach(el => el.unsubscribe());
    }


}
```

Comment: You're using the OnPush strategy, and you're violating the constraints it imposes, since you change the state of the component by subscribing to an observable. Remove the OnPush strategy, or use the async pipe instead of subscribing in the component. https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2018/09/27/angular-performances-part-4/

Comment: A demo code, to learn about `ngRx` https://github.com/shashankvivek/Angular4/tree/master/ngRx/Employee_DB_Effects .  I hope it'll help you understand the complexity with a simple example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `OnPush` change detection strategy due to which change detector is not checking the component. You can manually perform change detection by injecting ChangeDetectorRef and calling it's `detectChanges` method inside the subscribe block.